# to find number of items bought by any customer at particular time

Tags: mysql

i have a sales table which contain `customer_id` `time_id` 
i want to count the products bought by a customer at one time_id.

i am running query

```
select customer_id,time_id,count(time_id) as count from sales where customer_id=2094 group by time_id.
```

this query runs and give the result but i have different customer_ids in another customer table then i run this query

```
select customer_id,time_id,count(time_id) as count from sales where customer_id in (select customer_id from customer) group by time_id.
```

but it is not showing exact result.

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is "all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT clause MUST be included in the GROUP BY clause".

Comment: @Strawberry how can we do that.

Comment: By including the GROUP BY clause all non-aggregated columns which appear in the SELECT. It's not rocket science.